# Trying to understand how properties in C# works

Tags: c#, variables, get, set

I am trying to get user input and check if its the Max number entered by the user; the max number should be saved to the `maxResult` variable and i am trying to do so get and set used by C#
following is the code:

```
    //Number entred by user
    private static int intJudgeResult { get; set; }

    // varibale where to save the max entred number
    private static int _maxresult;
    private static int maxResult {
        get
        {
            return _maxresult;
        }
        set
        {
            if (intJudgeResult > intJudgeResult )
                maxResult = intJudgeResult ;
        }
    }
```

I know that man could easly set the `maxResult = intJudgeResult`but i am trying to use get and set for the first time:P
the thing is that `_maxresult` is never inithialized, any idea how to fix this..

Answer (score 2):

A couple of errors jump out here...

This will never be true:

```
if (intJudgeResult > intJudgeResult)
```

I think you meant this:

```
if (intJudgeResult > _maxResult)
```

Also, this is a stack overflow exception waiting to happen:

```
maxResult = intJudgeResult;
```

You meant to set the backing variable, not the property:

```
_maxResult = intJudgeResult;
```

(Setting the property from within the property would result in the setter infinitely calling itself.)

As for *initializing* the value... Since it's an `int` it will default to `0`.  Value types *must* have a value.  You can always initialize it to something else if you like:

```
private static int _maxresult = 1;
```

Any compiler warning about not initializing the value was probably the result of the second issue above, since you weren't setting the value itself.

Answer (score 0):

First don't overuse static.

```
//Number entered by user
private int _judgeResult
private int JudgeResult { 
    get 
    {
        return _judgeResult;
    }
    set
    {
        _judgeResult = value;
        if (MaxResult < value) 
            MaxResult = value;
    } 
}

// variable where to save the max entered number
private int _maxresult;
private int MaxResult {
    get
    {
        return _maxresult;
    }
    set
    {
        _maxresult = value;
    }
}
```

Comment: How does this address the initialisation of the `_maxresult` field?

Comment: _maxresult will default to 0, as it is an int.  And will correctly be set to the max value when JudgeResult is set to a value higher than the current MaxResult

Comment: Perhaps you could include an explanation of that in your answer instead of just posting code that doesn't appear to answer the question, even if it may address the issue that the poster actually has.

Answer (score 0):

Your setter is not correct and you have several problems with it.

The first problem is that `maxResult = intJudgeResult;` should be `_maxResult = intJudgeResult`.

The way you have it now should be causing an infinite loop. This change alone won't fix your problem though

Your second problem is that the condition `intJudgeResult > intJudgeResult` will never be true.

The third problem is that you haven't used the special variable `value` to accept the input value into property.

I think this is what you want, though I would say properties probably aren't the best way of doing this

```
//Number entred by user
private static int _intJudgeResult;
private static int intJudgeResult 
{ 
    get
    {
        return _intJudgeResult; //EDIT: Missed the _ before
    } 
    set
    {
        intJudgeResult = value;
        maxResult = intJudgeResult;
    }

// varibale where to save the max entred number
private static int _maxresult = 0;
private static int maxResult 
{
    get
    {
        return _maxresult;
    }
    set
    {
        if (value > intJudgeResult )
            _maxResult = value;
    }
}
```

Comment: you mean `_maxresult = value` ?

Comment: this will return System.StackOverflowException

Comment: Where do you believe you will get System.StackOverflowException from?

You can have `maxResult = value` or `maxResult = intJudgeResult` in `intJudgeResult` at this stage it doesn't make a difference
You don't want to to use `_maxResult` in `intJudgeResult` using `_maxResult` will by pass the logic test you put in setter for maxResult.

Ideally `_maxResult` will only be accessed by the getter and setter from the `maxResult` property

Comment: what _maxResult?? look at ur code u dont declare somewhere do u mean _maxresult?

Comment: @Puddler Kob_24 is right, the `StackOverflowException` happens on this line: `intJudgeResult = value;`, it should be `_intJudgeResult = value;`. You also have casing issues with `_maxResult` and `_maxresult`.

Answer (score 0):

In your example code the `_maxresult` member is a standard static field.  Initialize it the same way you would any other field:

```
private static int _maxresult = 0;
```

If you want to delay initialization then you will need some way to indicate that the field has not yet been initialized.  For an `int` you could assign it some invalid value as a field initializer, then test for that value in your property's `get` method.

Answer (score 0):

This would solve the problem:

```
    public static int _judgeresult;
    private static int judgeResult
    {
        get { return _judgeresult; }
        set {
            _judgeresult = value;
            if (value > MaxValue)
                MaxValue = value;
        }
    }

    private static int MaxValue { get; set; }
```